# django-leaflet: How can you add layer controls to the controlLayer for the Tiles created in settings.py?

Tags: django, leaflet, django-leaflet

I have map tile layers configured in my settings.py and they properly appear and work.

When my site is loaded, I am also getting data to add two layers to the map and I also add them to a controlLayer.

```
controlLayers.addOverlay(restaurantMarkers, 'Restaurants');
controlLayers.addOverlay(parksMarkers, 'Parks');
```

and then I add the control layer to the map

```
var controlLayers = L.control.layers().addTo(map);
```

This all works, but they are in their own control layer separate from the tiles control layer so now I have two control layers.

How do I add additional controls to the controlLayer created for the Tiles?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the dev team (on github)...

`map.layerscontrol` is the attribute that the Tiles from the `settings.py` are added to.

So if in your own page you use `var controlLayers = map.layerscontrol;` and then add layers to it `controlLayers.addOverlay(layerData, "Layer Name")` you will have a single control layer.

More info in Github https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to lay one layer on the other. Here is described how to do it. (Basemap tile with no labels, Transparent labels-only tile, Labels on top of basemap)
http://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: Not exactly, using Django-leaflet's settings, you can specify tile layers and they show up in a control layer. I want to add additional layers, loaded when the page loads, to that same control layer. So far, I've only been able to add them to a new control layer. Thanks for the suggestion though.